# OneToMany mapping on table with composite key returns empty list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been struggled into OneToMany mapping on entity with composite primary key when I try to get List of items of child table.
I have entitties Person and PhoneNumbers. One person may have multiple phone numbers. PhoneNumber entity have primary key consist of two fields: id and person_id which is foreign key to Person entity.

This is a database schema:

**person:**

id (pk)
person_name

**phone_number:**

id (pk)
person_id (pk)(fk)
phone_number

Person class

```
@Entity(name = "person")
public class Person {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "person_name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

// constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

PhoneNumber class

```
public class PhoneNumber {
@EmbeddedId
private PhoneNumberPk phoneNumberPk;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Person person;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;

// constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

PhoneNumberPk class

```
@Embeddable
public class PhoneNumberPk {
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "person_id")
private Long personId;

// constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

Problem is when I get Person entity from database and call person.getPhoneNumbers() I always get empty list. Hibernate debugging shows that query that fetch data from phone_number table is executed when I call person.getPhoneNumbers() but I always get empty list.

I'm using Spring Boot - Spring Data JPA 2.0.7 and Hibernate 5.2.17